# Sending Test Emails

Tags: email

I've just started using Civi at a new org and I cannot figure out how to send a test email. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find a tutorial either???

Do I have to remove all the recipients and add a test list group only? I sincerely hope not!

Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't found it already, you might find this useful: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the mailing form when you're designing it, in the middle of the bottom section, there's a spot to send a test.

[image]

---

If using mosaico there's also a test button in the top right in the mosaico editor.

[image]

Comment: Brittany - also if your 'send test' is greyed out in the traditional mailer, it may be that you are missing some tokens (but site should notify you of this) or havent' entered a Mailing Name, Subject etc etc